# Is there the possibility of customizing the level names of org-latex-classes?

Tags: org-mode, latex

I tried to export from org to pdf with:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
           '("thesis"
              "\\documentclass{thesis}
    [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
    [PACKAGES]
    [EXTRA]"
              ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
              ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
              ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
              ("\\minisec{%s}" . "\\minisec*{%s}")
              ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
              ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))))
```

But when I make a level 4 header (like so `****`) then it resolves as `\item` instead of `\minisec` in the .tex-file. If I use in the config the "standard" (subsubsection) instead of (minisec) it works flawlessly.

If it is not possible to change the standards, can I perform a sed command or something like %s/subsubsection/minisec/g after the transformation to latex and before the compilation to pdf (automaticly)?

**Update:** Ok, thanks to NickD I could solve it halfway. No I set my class to:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
           '("thesis"
              "\\documentclass{thesis}
    [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
    [PACKAGES]
    [EXTRA]"
              ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
              ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
              ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
              ("\\minisec{%s}" . "\\minisec*{%s}"))))
```

because I do not need 6 headline levels. My problem was, that I thought if I configure a class like this, that I do not have to add the option `#+OPTIONS: H:4` to my org-mode file. Is there also a way to define in the class configuration that every document with that class has the option of `H:4`?

Comment: Try `#+OPTIONS: H:6` if you want to go all the way down to `subparagraph`; although I don't understand why `subsubsection` works.

Comment: I think there was some missunderstanding, so I updated my Question to clarify what I want to achieve.